# Branching strategy for ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, branching-strategy

We are facing challenges with ADF deployment with multiple teams working on same ADF for different use cases. When we move from Dev to Test to Prod we find difficult to deploy the code.

1. Teams working on their on working branches (feature)
2. This will go to collab branch and publish
3. When we move to SIT then we take it to another branch 'integration' branch
4. If team A push their code onto SIT it will be done form integration branch.
5. After some days team B also move to SIT, need to merge code to integration branch
6. But when team A moves to Prod later they also get the code from team B as well

How can we resolve this situation? We really do not want other teams code which is testing phase to move to Prod.
Are we missing something in branching strategy?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi82I.png)

Answer (score 0):

keep your QA release on say Integration branch

keep your prod release on say master branch..

keep 2 hot fix branches for each team

prod bug fixes will then go from dev branch to.prod thru respective hotfix branches

also same bug fixes will go to integration branch

Comment: was this helpful ?